# Accidentally redirecting after displaying Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I think the title is clear, but to be sure: I'm not looking to redirect after showing the modal, which is the only thing my searches yielded.

The page is incorrectly redirecting elsewhere but I'm not sure why.

I have a list of entries (basically just the scaffolding CRUD that MVC generates) and when a button is clicked, a modal is to pop up and display a little information via AJAX (eventually it'll be a form, but that's unimportant right now). The modal pops up for just an instant, then I'm redirected to one of the `Details` pages.

The modal is supposed to be using a partial view from `Archive/{id}`, which it does, but then I am immediately sent to `Details/{id}`. I don't know where I'm telling that redirect to happen.

I'm using the default routing of `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. Chrome debugger shows no errors.

_ArchiveModal.cshtml

```
@model EDB.Models.ProductModel

<div>

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close btn-modal-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="archiveModalLabel">Archive?</h4>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <p>
        Test test testing all day, these are words
    </p>

</div>
```

`div` in Index.cshtml

```
<div id="archiveModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="archiveModalContent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript / jQuery

```
$(document).ready {
    $(".modal-anchor-archive").click(function () {
        var modalUrl = '@Url.Action("Archive")' + "/" + $(this).data("id");
        var options = {
            "backdrop": "static",
            keyboard: true
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: modalUrl,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#archiveModalContent").html(data);
                $("#archiveModal").modal(options);
                $("#archiveModal").modal("show");
                debugger; // Stopping here shows that the modal does display
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });

        $(".btn-modal-close").click(function () {
            $("#archiveModal").modal("hide");
        });
    });
}
```

Button

```
<span class="btn btn-warning modal-anchor-archive" data-id="@item.ID">Archive</span>
```

Controller action

```
public ActionResult Archive(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    ProductModel productModel = db.Products.Find(id);
    if (productModel == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return PartialView("_ArchiveModal", productModel);
}
```

Comment: What does your action method look like? Do you have any error logic - such as, on error direct to "details" page?

Comment: @wahwahwah Realized I forgot that as you were typing that. I don't have any error logic that I know of, unless something was generated somewhere (save for the little bit of logic in the action method).

Comment: Since you are saying the model is shown for an instant use something like, "$(".modal-anchor-archive").click(function (e) { " and on success e.preventDefault(); so that click of the button doesn't submit the form or redirect to any page.

Comment: @Shan Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/7eGyJbe.png)? Not sure if that's right, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can we see your ExceptionModel code?

Comment: @B.Fitzgerald How would that help?

Comment: Does your ExceptionModel hold actual exceptions that are being thrown in your code? Maybe one of them is being caught and that redirects you to the Details page. I'm not sure I'm just reaching for something here.

Comment: @B.Fitzgerald Oh, no, I should probably edit that to something more mundane, has nothing to do with code exceptions.

Comment: There is probably a form in your index view. Remove that and it shouldnt redirect.
It should be something like: @Html.BeginForm(......

Comment: @Abdullah You're right, there is a form... but I need it. Actually, I may have a workaround for that. Why is it that I can't have a form and a modal, though?

Comment: Sinjai - you can have a form in your modal. @Abdullah is helping troubleshoot. If he's right, we know the offending culprit and can help you fix it. As it stands, there's got to be something happening outside of the code you've posted - most of these comments are geared towards narrowing that down...

Comment: Do you have an action that can be executed from the page where the modal appears that redirects to the `/details/` url? If so, it's firing immediately after your modal opens.

Comment: Then move form inside modal and move your button outside of form. That way you can have form you need.

Comment: Not sure how I overlooked this earlier. The row containing the button I'm clicking has an OnClick jQuery event on it. Not sure how to fix that, but at least I know the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here.

It turns out it was a problem with jQuery's [event propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869011/button-click-event-triggering-wrong-event-handler) feature. The row that contains the modal button has an `onClick` event registered to it which redirects to `Details`. I can't believe that slipped my mind.

The fix was hilariously simple.

```
$(".modal-anchor-archive").click(function (e) {
    // Prevent the event from "bubbling up" to this element's container(s)
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Other code
}
```